# Computer not detecting any OS, how to manually add os entry

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

My system crashed earlier today and is not working properly.

It's saying no disk found.., and not detecting the os.

I tried doing "fixboot" "fixmbr" using the OS DVD but nothing happened.

The drives contain all the data though, as i can see it using command line.

Since i can access CLI (command line interface) is there a way to add the OS entry manually to grub, etc so that the computer can find the os and load it.

I did everything else, checked the hardware and also reset BIOS settings, but nothing happened.

Please help me out guys.. i don't want to lose my OS :)

System config : Windows 7 OS
4 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD

Comment: You've better posted this question in superuser.com

Comment: This isn't appropriate for StackOverflow.  Go to superuser.com instead.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want fixed.  If you have grub, then you have/had Linux.  If you put a Win7 MBR back on the disk you're going to lose access to any existing Linux.  Is that what you want?

Comment: it's simple, the windows installation got corrupted (c drive) and i cannot boot to windows as the boot info is not available as well.., what i think is.................. I will format it

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this in the past, I've simply gone into the BIOS, specified "no disk", saved, and rebooted. On reboot, I respecified the disk and the issue resolved itself.